# How do we create a 32-bit build of Perl 5.12.3 in /usr/local on Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: perl, macos, build

For one reason or another we need to create a custom 32-bit build of Perl 5.12.3 in /usr/local on Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

Can anyone explain the process or point us the direction of a tutorial or example?

Comment: When you `Configure` your perl build, there is a step that asks: `Any additional cc flags?` If you add `-m32` you'll only build a 32-bit object code. There are some other linker flags you need to specify that I missed just now, but that is a starting point I guess.

Comment: This guy appears to have the answer: http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.dbi.users/2010/06/msg35120.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Snowleopard the kernel runs in 32bit mode and the userland mostly in 64bit mode. The kernel is able to run 32bit and 64bit userland apps without a problem. 
You need to tell the perl build system to create a 32bit only binary. This is done by setting the -arch gcc flag.

For a simple singe file app you would do it like this:

```
gcc -arch i386 -o app app.m -lobjc -framework CoreFoundation -framework Cocoa
```

In your case you have to pass the arch flag to the build system.
Iam not a perl expert but i would configure perl like this:

```
./Configure -Dprefix=/usr/local -A ccflags="-arch i386"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your system doesn't have 64bit kernel extensions turned on, then you should just be able to build Perl straight from source and pass DESTDIR=/usr/local on the make install command line.  If the system is in 64bit mode, you'll need to look up how to cross-compile for i386, which isn't something I've had to do before as I just build perl for my native architecture, or install from a package.

Comment: I'm not sure that's enough. I boot a 32-bit kernel and my locally built perl is 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it using Perlbrew:

1. Install [Perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/)
2. Make sure you have followed all of the proper steps including adding the bit to the end of `.bash_profile`.
3. Run the following (for perl 5.14.2, with threading. Adjust as necessary for other perl versions and options) (Thanks to [WildPerl](http://wildperl.com/2011/07/padre-on-osx-dmg-now-on-leopard-snow-leopard-and-lion/) for this bit of wisdom):

   perlbrew install 5.14.2 -ders -Dusethreads -Duseithreads -Accflags="-arch i386" -Accflags="-B/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/gcc" -Accflags="-B/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/gcc" -Accflags="-isystem/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include" -Accflags="-F/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks" -Accflags="-mmacosx-version-min=10.5" -Aldflags="-arch i386 -Wl,-search_paths_first" -Aldflags="-Wl,-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk" -Aldflags="-mmacosx-version-min=10.5" -Alddlflags="-arch i386 -Wl,-search_paths_first" -Alddlflags="-Wl,-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk" -Alddlflags="-mmacosx-version-min=10.5" -Duseshrplib
4. If you have a newer version of Xcode with the Developer SDKs as part of the app bundle, you'll need to create a symlink to them from /Developer:

   sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/ /Developer
5. Install the local copy of cpanm:

   perlbrew install-cpanm
6. After that finishes, go to the place where perlbrew installed perl (on my system that is: `~/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.2/lib/5.14.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level/` and edit `Config.pm` to change this line:

   cc => 'cc',

to this:

```
cc => 'cc -m32',
```